# Why does setting the element display property to flex in CSS change the behaviour of the JS onclick event with 'event.target'?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a basic list going on, with the HTML structure like this:

```
<ul class="list">
{...}
  <li class="item">Ellipse</li>
{...}
```

Then I use some JS to add `button`s to delete items, so the end structure is like this:

```
<ul class="list">
{...}
  <li class="item">Ellipse <button>Delete item</button></li>
{...}
```

I also have a function to strike through the list elements on click by toggling a CSS class:

```
let ul = document.querySelector('.list');
{...}

function markAsDone (event) {  
  let target = event.target;
  target.classList.toggle('done');
}
{...}

ul.addEventListener('click', markAsDone);
```

This works as expected (e.g. the list item is struck through). However, if I change the list items' display property to flex in CSS:

```
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 300px ;
}
```

And then click on the item, the text of the button also is struck through, unlike before! Since I've started writing this, I no longer know which behaviour feels more 'wrong' to me, lol.

The full code is on Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/kykuy/pen/WNvMmay). Try clicking the items in the list, then uncomment the CSS style for `.item` to see what I mean.

My uneducated guess would be that the answer to this is in the way the flex containers treat the items in them. However, my understanding of it is very limited, so I've come to you for an answer.

Comment: Better if you post a minimal runable snippet.

Comment: It doesn’t change anything about the event. Log `event.target` to console in that function, and you will see it is the same element in both cases, the `LI` itself. You can also toggle the `display: flex` on the LI in your dev tools, and you will see the change happening then, so this has _nothing_ whatsoever to do with your event handling. This is a pure CSS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answering "WHY" let's have a look at the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration).

> The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any effect on the decoration of the ancestor.

Your code is fine. This behavior is consistent with spec, `text-decoration` affect all children *(with some exceptions)*. There is only one thing you can do about it: just try to avoid the `text-decoration` on the parent element, if you doт't want this `text-decoration` to be applied to the children.

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Buttons are `display: inline-block;` by default, that's why they look fine unless the parent container takes control over it, such as flex or grid.

Here is an example:

```css
.item {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;

  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

.item-flex { display: flex; }
.item-inline-flex { display: inline-flex; }

.item-grid { display: grid; }
.item-inline-grid { display: inline-grid; }

.item-table { display: table; }
.item-inline-table { display: inline-table; }

.item-inline { display: inline; }
.item-inline-block { display: inline-block; }

.item span, .item button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: overline underline;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  display:
  <span>block</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-flex">
  display:
  <span>flex</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-grid">
  display: <span>grid</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-table">
  display:
  <span>table</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-inline">
  display:
  <span>inline</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-inline-block">
  display:
  <span>inline-block</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-inline-flex">
  display:
  <span>inline-flex</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-inline-grid">
  display:
  <span>inline-grid</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-inline-table">
  display:
  <span>inline-table</span>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap your text with `span` will resolve your issue. check below snippet.

i am not sure but you apply `done` class to `parent element` which strike through both element.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.smash');
let input = document.querySelector('.userinput');
let ul = document.querySelector('.list');
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list > li');

function inputLengthValue() {
  let result = input.value.length;
  return result;
}

function createListElem() {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  li.classList.add('item');
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";

  let delButton = document.createElement('button');
  delButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Delete item'));
  li.appendChild(delButton);
  delButton.addEventListener('click', removeItem)
}

function addListItemOnclick() {
  if (inputLengthValue() != 0) {
    createListElem();
  }
}

function addListItemOnEnterPress(event) {
  if (inputLengthValue() != 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElem();
  }
}

function createDeleteButtons() {
  for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    let delButton = document.createElement('button');
    delButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Delete item'));
    listItems[i].appendChild(delButton);
    delButton.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
  }
}

function markAsDone(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  target.classList.toggle('done');
}

function removeItem(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  target.parentNode.remove();
}


button.addEventListener('click', addListItemOnclick);
input.addEventListener('keydown', addListItemOnEnterPress);
ul.addEventListener('click', markAsDone);
createDeleteButtons(); // create delete btn for default items
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">Some list</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your text" class="userinput">
<button class="smash">Add item</button>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item"><span>Romboid</span></li>
  <li class="item"><span>Square</span></li>
  <li class="item"><span>Circle</span></li>
  <li class="item"><span>Ellipse</span></li>
  <li class="item"><span>Rectangle</span></li>
  <li class="item"><span>Oval</span></li>
</ul>
```